# Unable to install my-sql in Ubuntu after uninstalling it

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04

[image: Error message screen shot]

Can anybody help me?

```
pradeep 22:36:19 pradeep $ dpkg -l | grep mysql | grep ii
ii  dbconfig-mysql                              2.0.4ubuntu1                                                all          dbconfig-common MySQL/MariaDB support
ii  mysql-client-5.7                            5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                                     amd64        MySQL database client binaries
ii  mysql-client-core-5.7                       5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                                     amd64        MySQL database core client binaries
ii  mysql-common                                5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                                     all          MySQL database common files, e.g. /etc/mysql/my.cnf
ii  mysql-server                                5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                                     all          MySQL database server (metapackage depending on the latest version)
ii  mysql-server-5.7                            5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                                     amd64        MySQL database server binaries and system database setup
ii  mysql-server-core-5.7                       5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                                     amd64        MySQL database server binaries
ii  php-mysql                                   1:7.0+44+deb.sury.org~xenial+1                              all          MySQL module for PHP [default]
ii  php7.0-mysql                                7.0.10-2+deb.sury.org~xenial+1                              amd64        MySQL module for PHP
```

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep mysql | grep ii` check this and post the result here. And no image post the text.

Comment: pasted the text check the question itself

Comment: you have upgraded the mysql server

Comment: ok so what i have to do now?

Comment: `mysql_upgrade` try this

Comment: Is that you have executed command

Comment: pradeep 22:51:12 pradeep ⮀ mysql_upgrade
mysql_upgrade: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) while connecting to the MySQL server
Upgrade process encountered error and will not continue.

Comment: check this path `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` either it is there or not.

Comment: no there is no mysqld in run folder

Comment: `ps -aux | grep mysql` check either mysqld is running or not.

Comment: no its no running dude!

Comment: start it dude. And then check

Comment: dude im not able to install it then how to start?

Comment: `service mysql start` can you check this

Comment: pradeep 23:20:25 pradeep ⮀ service mysql start
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: Do you want to install again

Comment: yes of-course dude can you help?

Comment: Ok...if this answer helped you then accept it by clicking green tick. And I cannot give you the installation procedure here, because it is not relevant to the question. I am giving my email just ping me.

Comment: Deleting email id comment if you are done then let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you upgrade the mysql server it has to upgrade the table aslo.

Few possible option to check

- So you need to run `mysql_upgrade`.
- Check either you socket exits or not.
- Check either you mysqld running or not.